# Is a Union Query needed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need a little help writing a query. I have this data...

```
vDir    iNumber
North   19
North   27
North   29
North   31
South   46
South   49
South   51
South   61
```

I need to query the data and have an output something like this

```
vDir    iLowNumber    iHiNumber
North   19            27
North   27            29
North   29            31
South   46            49
South   49            51
South   51            61
```

The idea here is to select the direction, the LowNum and then the nextNumber. Also when the direction changes to start over. (That's why I think I need a Union, maybe get the North, then Union the South). Notice too the highest number in each direction doesn't create a record because there is no higher number. The first set has 8 records, and the query result is only 6.

How can I create a query that will do this? Also this is a 2008 SQL Database so I can use 2008 TSQL. I'm really curious how to do this in SQL. Thanks guys!

Comment: I don't believe Union is going to be necessary here. I'm removing that from the tag list and adding sql-server so that it gets more eyes.

Comment: Looks like one of the problems on http://ask.sqlservercentral.com - Not sure if I can find the right one immediately, but if you ask it over there you'll probably get a quick answer!

Comment: Questions:  DO the iLowNumber / iHiNumbers only increase?  and do you ever get a single entry for vDir in the sequence?

Comment: No, literally this is the dataset. Just these 8 records. And if new records were added, it would one record for South and one for North

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
SELECT
    T1.vDir,
    T1.iNumber AS iLowNumber,
    T2.iNumber AS iHiNumber
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.vDir = T1.vDir AND
    T2.iNumber > T1.iNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T3 ON
    T3.vDir = T1.vDir AND
    T3.iNumber > T1.iNumber AND
    T3.iNumber < T2.iNumber
WHERE
    T3.vDir IS NULL  -- If this is NULL it means that no rows exist between T1 and T2
```

Comment: The sub-query solution matches more with the way I pictured the problem, but this is a very elegant solution. For data-sets getting large, it should be pretty fast, too.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a very clean and clear solution! Produces the correct output. Well Done!

Answer (score 1):

```
    select a.vDir, 
           a.iNumber as iLowNumber, 
           b.iNumber as iHiNumber 
      from TheTable a
inner join TheTable b on a.vDir = b.vDir
                  and a.iNumber < b.iNumber 
                  and not exists(select 1 
                                   from TheTable c 
                                  where a.vDir = b.vDir
                                    and a.iNumber < c.iNumber 
                                    and c.iNumber < b.iNumber)
```

Interesting that there are 3 different answers so far, each with different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it well

```
select * from(
 select direction,inumber as low,
 (select top(1) inumber  from cte as b where b.direction=a.direction
 and b.INumber>a.inumber) as high
 from cte as a
 ) as x where high is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

TO my mind the most natural solution is:

```
select t1.vdir, t1.inumber as lownumber, min(t2.inumber) as highnumber
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.vdir=t1.vdir
  and t2.inumber>t1.inumber
group by t1.vdir, t1.inumber
order by t1.vdir, t1.inumber
```

How the performance of this compares to other solutions I haven't investigated.